# Can't install 0.4.1 (latest) from USB with nVidia 1060 (SOLVED)

Tags: boot, nvidia

Hello Elementary OS support community,

First, I'm a lifetime Linux user - so I'm very familiar with the intricacies of installing and working with Linux. Second, I can't seem to install 0.4.1 on my computer that has an nVidia 1060 6GB video card in it, as it get's stuck while it's trying to boot with 2 errors, as you can see here: [boot errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhrwp.jpg)

If I added "modprobe.blacklist=nouveau" to the kernel boot parameters, it get's rid of the second error, but I get no further because the first is still there.

My system configuration is as follows:
 - Asus A88x-Pro Motherboard
 - AMD A10-7850K Processor
 - nVidia 1060 6GB video card
 - 8GB RAM
 - Samsung EVO 250GB SSD

Any and all pointers would be appreicated. And if anyone needs further information about my setup, please let me know.

Thanks guys!
-Ben

UPDATE: I was able to eventually figure this out, although it was a bit more manual labor than I had hoped. For anyone else that wants to try this, here you go:

1. Goto your BIOS and make sure you use the internal GFX rather than external graphics card.
2. Make sure you're physically connected to the internal graphics card via HDMI or whatever is appropriate.
3. Boot from USB, and hit "e" to edit the boot options when the boot from USB first starts.
4. Before the "--" at the end of the boot options line, add the following: "nomodeset rdblacklist=nouveau"
5. Install normally, and then reboot.
6. Install updates from App Center, and then choose to install the appropriate nVidia drivers from the Updates tab.
7. Reboot back to the BIOS, re-enable external graphics cards, then shut down.
8. Reconnect your monitor(s) as you wish.
9. Power up the PC and proceed to enjoy Elementary OS in all it's glory.
10. (optional) Develop some awesome apps for Elementary OS and submit them to the App Center!

Comment: You might want to post your answer as an answer and not as an update to your question. This might help people to find it later.

Comment: lemonslice: I tried, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so apparently. I'm still new to stack exchange though, so if there is something else I can do, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve nvidia problem during boot you can add `nouveau.modeset=0` before `quiet splash`. This way you can install the os and do the same to first boot and install propriety nvidia drivers.